# Type.GetType() bring null

Tags: c#, types

I use this function, to get the type of some enums, from string:

when I use it for system enum- like `Type.GetType("System.ConsoleColor")`- I got the type,

but when I use it for enum whitch I declared- like

`Type.GetType("SignalModule.Implementation.SubscriberType")`

I got null

when i tried in the immediate-window to key this orders: *

```
SignalModule.Implementation.SubscriberType
```

I got the truth type:

```
SignalModule.Implementation.SubscriberType EventSignalChange: EventSignalChange Polling: Polling *Type.GetType(SignalModule.Implementation.SubscriberType)
```

I got the error:

```
'SignalModule.Implementation.SubscriberType' is a 'type'
```

which is not valid in the given context

```
Type.GetType("SignalModule.Implementation.SubscriberType")
```

I got null

what should be the problem?

Comment: Please be much more sensitive about formatting.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 4):

you need to use full name. for example if i created:

```
public class CarParts
{
  public string PartId { get; set; }
  public int PartCost { get; set; }


  public DataGridViewButtonCell Edit { get; set; }
}
```

in dll named "WindowsFormsApplication5"

and i want it's type i need to do:

```
Type.GetType("WindowsFormsApplication5.CarParts, WindowsFormsApplication5, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
```

to get the type

the easiest way to know the full name is to get an instance of the class you want, get `GetType` and get a `Type` class instance. the look at the `AssemblyQualifiedName` property

Comment: how can I know whitch attribute include in "full name" and what is the format of the full name?

Comment: hi, thanks. I got it good. but my problem is the `Version` attribute:  I bring the string from data source whitch won't be changed when I update versions of dlls. there is way to skirt?

Comment: @chaya the version is the assembly version. if you update the version it's gonna be problematic... i think you should post a new question about it, because i don't understand enough about it....

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like the type in question is public and in scope, why not simply use:

```
typeof(SignalModule.Implementation.SubscriberType)
```

instead? With appropriate `using` directives it might even be simplified to `typeof(SubscriberType)`.

The problem with the static `GetType(string)` method is that you need to give the cumbersome *assembly-qualified name* of the type **unless** the type happens to be in the specific assembly `mscorlib`. Read [the doc page for that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for more information.

If the type is not in scope, for example because it is not from the current assembly and not public, or if you can't reference the assembly, then you have to use `GetType(string)`.

Comment: I got the string from data source as string, and I want to convert it to type by using the GetType method

Comment: @chaya Is it always from the same assembly? Because then you can use the instance method `yourAssembly.GetType(" ... ")` like @xanatos says in his answer. The good thing about that method, as compared to the static method on `Type`, is that you need only the namespace-qualified name in the string. The assembly name is not needed since the assembly is clearly known (it is `yourAssembly`).

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on what Jeppe Stig Nielsen wrote, there is another path if you really really need to get a type by name:

```
Type type = typeof(SomeTypeInTheSameAssemblyAsYourType).Assembly
               .GetType("SignalModule.Implementation.SubscriberType")
```

The `Assembly.GetType(string)` clearly search for the type in the selected `Assembly`.

Comment: When one uses strings, also one has to remember the ".NET syntax" for the type names which differs from what C# uses in some cases. For example the nested type which C# calls `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` needs the string `"System.Environment+SpecialFolder"` with a plus, and the generic type `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<,>` (with two type parameters) needs the string ``"System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"`` (and this can become more complicated if you need a _constructed_ generic type).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I have to tell the truth... I cheat heavily... and let the .NET generate the name for me the first time: `var name = typeof(Environment).GetNestedTypes().First(p => p.Name == "SpecialFolder").FullName;
    var name2 = typeof(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, int>).FullName;`